# Exporting random rows to excel file based on int value

Tags: c#

So I have my report printing out exactly what I want (almost).  Now I just have to get one feature finished.  I have a number that is generated and placed into a variable called percentage.

percentage equals the the rounded number of all the licenses in the database that allAttendeeLicenseNos pulls in multiplied by the number that is entered in by the user multiplied .01 to make it a percentage.

So my goal is to see all the attendees, and say okay this person only wants a percentage of them, but it doesn't matter which ones so I am going to grab random rows until the percentage number is there.

Again, please be patient as I am very new to C# and am learning.

```
        var percentage = Math.Round(allAttendeeLicenseNos.Count() * Percentage * 0.01);

        var allAttendeeData = _mii.LicenseeRecords.Where(r => allAttendeeLicenseNos.Contains(r.LicenseNumber)).Where(i => i.LicenseStatus.Equals(chosenLicenseStatus)).ToList();

        var retval = _mapper.Map<List<DLILicense>, List<RandomAuditViewModel>>(allAttendeeData);

        using (var exs = new ExcelPackage())
        {
            var worksheet = exs.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("RandomAuditReport");
            var row = 1;
            var col = 1;

            var properties = typeof(RandomAuditViewModel).GetProperties();
            foreach (var field in properties)
            {
                worksheet.Cells[row, col].Style.Font.Bold = true;
                var displayName = field.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>() != null ?
                    field.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>().GetName() :
                    field.Name;
                worksheet.SetValue(row, col, displayName);
                col++;
            }
            col = 1;
            row++;


            retval.ForEach(i =>
            {

                var periodOrdinal = _ce.Events
                    .Where(e => e.Attendees.Select(a => a.LicenseNumber).Contains(i.LicenseNumber))
                    .Select(e => e.Course.CertificationPeriod)
                    .OrderBy(p => p.StartDate)
                    .ToList()
                    .IndexOf(thePeriod) + 1;

                i.MetRequirements = determineIfCeMet(i.LicenseNumber, i.LicenseTypeCode, i.DateOfOriginalLicensure, periodOrdinal, thePeriod.Id, thePeriod.EndDate, thePeriod.Board);

                foreach (var field in properties)
                {
                    if (field.GetCustomAttribute<DataTypeAttribute>().DataType.Equals(DataType.Date))
                    {
                        var value = ((DateTime)field.GetValue(i));
                        worksheet.Cells[row, col].Style.Numberformat.Format = "MM/dd/yyyy";
                        worksheet.Cells[row, col].Formula = "=DATE(" + value.Year + "," + value.Month + "," + value.Day + ")";
                    }
                    else worksheet.SetValue(row, col, field.GetValue(i));
                    col++;
                }
                col = 1;
                row++;

            });
            return exs.GetAsByteArray();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like below?

```
retval.ForEach(i =>
        {
            if(retval.IndexOf(i) == percentage)
               break;

            var periodOrdinal = _ce.Events
                .Where(e => e.Attendees.Select(a => a.LicenseNumber).Contains(i.LicenseNumber))
                .Select(e => e.Course.CertificationPeriod)
                .OrderBy(p => p.StartDate)
                .ToList()
                .IndexOf(thePeriod) + 1;

            i.MetRequirements = determineIfCeMet(i.LicenseNumber, i.LicenseTypeCode, i.DateOfOriginalLicensure, periodOrdinal, thePeriod.Id, thePeriod.EndDate, thePeriod.Board);

            foreach (var field in properties)
            {
                if (field.GetCustomAttribute<DataTypeAttribute>().DataType.Equals(DataType.Date))
                {
                    var value = ((DateTime)field.GetValue(i));
                    worksheet.Cells[row, col].Style.Numberformat.Format = "MM/dd/yyyy";
                    worksheet.Cells[row, col].Formula = "=DATE(" + value.Year + "," + value.Month + "," + value.Day + ")";
                }
                else worksheet.SetValue(row, col, field.GetValue(i));
                col++;
            }
            col = 1;
            row++;

        })
```

Where you're using this

**if(retval.IndexOf(i) == percentage)
               break;**

to determine if you've hit the percentage, then breaking out of the ForEach.

Comment: would I use an if statement or would a while statement be better?

Comment: You'd end up with the same result either, way.  I'd opt for the if because you need to iterate through the records anyways.  So if you use a while loop you still need an integer somewhere to count which row you're on and compare that to percentage: " while (myRowCountingInteger <= Percentage)" and then at the end of the loop you'd have "myRowCountingInteger++" so you're not really saving yourself much trouble so I think the if statement is an easier read when you come back months later and need to figure out what you were doing.

Comment: Also wanted to point out that this isn't giving you "random" rows, it's just giving you the first so many to meet the percentage requirement.

Comment: Thank you so much, this was such a simple solution to a problem I was seriously over thinking.  I will do some research on my own about IndexOf thank you for the help.